# Is SharePoint Designer 2010 open source?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I had an SharePoint interview today and was told that the company does not use SharePoint Designer 2010 because it is open source. This did not bother me because I have never been a great fan of it. However, I was not aware that I was open source. Therefore, my question - Is it actual open source?

Comment: Just a note, your interviewer didn't know what he/she was talking about, or didn't understand the definition of "open source". That could've been your initiative to tell them otherwise and made a good impression :). Good luck!

Comment: It's also a good indicator to run!

Comment: I agree with you Eric. Unfortunately, I need the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Open source means all the source code for SharePoint Designer is available for viewing and for possible extension. This is not the case much like most Microsoft products. SharePoint Designer is free to use though.

Comment: Yea, definitely no.  Microsoft does not have much that is open source.